# Removing the browse button when submitting an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to remove the browse button from the picture, It is more professional looking if i only keep the image of the profile picture, so that when the user clicks on the image, it opens the select file window... I managed to do that using the following code:

```
<label><img src="images/profile-picture.png"><input type="file" name="pic" id="pic" accept="image/*"></label>
```

Any idea how can i remove the annoying button and the text next to it ?

[image: This is my web interface]

Comment: see this demo would be useful to you. http://jsfiddle.net/VQJ9V/307/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** You can simply hide the input setting its display property to none:

```html
<label>
  <img src="http://www.insidefacebook.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/profile-150x150.png" id="profile-pic">
  <input type="file" name="pic" id="pic" accept="image/*" style="display: none;">
</label>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, wouldn't be the javascript function useless in this case ? Since the image is included in the label tag ?

Comment: Good point, indeed it is not necessary. I am gonna edit the answer.